# My rewrite url not working properly. When click my link they make more links and not taking exact path

Tags: php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php



RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ $1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/(admin|css|css/fonts|img|)/(.*)$ $2/$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^collections/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) collections.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) product.php?id=$1
```

making this type of urls

```
/collections/collections/collections/index
```

Or

```
/collections/collections/collections/product
```